# $1+\sqrt{2}$ seems special: its powers quickly approach integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$ \alpha = 1+\sqrt{2}$ has some interesting properties. One of which is that if you look at powers
\begin{align*}
\alpha^2 &= 3+2\sqrt{2} \approx 5.8284 \\
\alpha^3 & \approx 14.0710 \\
\alpha^4 & \approx 33.9705 \\
& \vdots \\
\alpha^{10} & \approx 6725.9998 \\
\alpha^{11} & \approx 16238.0000 \\
\vdots & 
\end{align*}
(values truncated, not rounded) then the sequence $\{ \alpha^n \}$ is "almost" an unbounded integer sequence. What is going on here? Is this property secondary to $\alpha$ being a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$? Can $\alpha$ be interpreted as a type of approximate eigenvalue? Does this behavior have to do with the continued fraction representation?
Other numbers such as $1+\sqrt{3}$ have a similar property, but they don't appear to "become integer" as quickly.

Comment: what the heck, what's up with that

Comment: i tested it for values up to like a^20. crazy

Comment: To recollection, the powers of the golden ratio, or something tied to it, exhibit a similar property. I wonder...

Comment: $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n + \left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n$ is an integer whenever $n \in \mathbb{N}$, because the odd terms in the binomial formula cancel out. But $\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: An interesting concept that seems to be related to all this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Comment: I was going to suggest the recursion $$a[k+2] = 2a[k+1]+a[k] \quad , \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$ which for $a[0]=a[1]=2$ has the solution $a[k] = (1+\sqrt{2})^k + (1-\sqrt{2})^k$.  Now of course $a[k]$ is an integer for all $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ but $(1-\sqrt{2})^k\rightarrow 0$ (similar to the darij grinberg comment).

Comment: I like @darijgrinberg's answer; reminds me of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167229/even-number-binomial/3167237#3167237); notice the sequence elements are close to **even** integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Near integers in powers of binomials with radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177151/near-integers-in-powers-of-binomials-with-radicals). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527827/11619), or many of the other threads with the same trick. This is so old hat that.... Never mind.

Answer (score 9):

The key fact here turns out to be that the conjugate (in this case in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$) of $1 + \sqrt{2}$, namely, $1 - \sqrt{2}$, has absolute value less than $1$.

If we expand 
$$(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$$
and apply the Binomial Theorem to both of the two powers, we find all of the nonintegral terms cancel, so $(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer for all $n$. But since $|1 - \sqrt{2}| < 1$, for large $n$ the term $(1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ tends to $0$ and so $$(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n \approx (1 + \sqrt{2})^n ,$$ and in particular $(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$ is close to an integer.

We can identify the sequence of integers that occurs, too: $(1 \pm \sqrt{2})$ are the roots of the polynomial $r^2 - 2 r - 1$, so $(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $$a_{n + 2} = 2 a_{n + 1} + a_n .$$ Evaluating at, say, $n = 0, 1$ gives $a_0 = a_1 = 2$, and these values and the recursion relation are enough to identify the sequence,
$$2, 2, 6, 14, 34, \ldots .$$
This sequence is [OEIS A002203](http://oeis.org/A002203), where its members are called the *companion Pell numbers*. (Its entries are exactly twice those of [OEIS A001333](http://oeis.org/A001333), $1, 1, 3, 7, 17, \ldots$, the numerators of the continued fraction convergents of $\sqrt{2}$.) Since the initial values are integers, as are the coefficients in the recursion relation, this gives an alternative way of seeing that $(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer for all $n$.

Finally, working backward, we can indeed interpret $1 + \sqrt{2}$ (and its conjugate) as eigenvalues of a suitable matrix: The companion matrix associated to the polynomial $r^2 - 2 r - 1$ above is $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&2}$, and its eigenvalues are $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. Then, a straightforward induction shows that 
$$\pmatrix{0&1\\1&2}^n \pmatrix{2&2\\2&6} = \pmatrix{a_n&a_{n + 1}\\a_{n + 1}&a_{n+ 2}} .$$

All of these phenomena, by the way are in close analogy to the more familiar case of the Golden Ratio, $\phi := \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$. (You might work these details out to check that you understand the above arguments.) Indeed, $1 + \sqrt{2}$ has a geometric interpretation analogous to that of the Golden Ratio, and by analogy it is sometimes called the [Silver Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio); in turn these are the first two (nontrivial) members of the infinite family $\frac{n + \sqrt{n^2 + 4}}{2}$, $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, of [metallic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean), all of which (except for the trivial case $n = 0$) have the key property re the conjugate.

[image]

Like you've observed, $1 + \sqrt{3}$ also has the key property, since $|1 - \sqrt{3}| < 1$. But $|1 - \sqrt{3}| > |1 - \sqrt{2}|$, so $|1 - \sqrt{3}|^n \to 0$ more slowly than $|1 - \sqrt{2}|^n \to 0$.

Comment: Interestingly the "silver ratio" is close to the format of the "silver screen" in movie theaters -- the traditional widescreen movie aspect ratio is often quoted as 1:2.40.

Comment: I didn't know that---that's a charming coincidence!

Comment: Did you search for duplicates at all?

Answer (score 4):

The roots of the polynomial $x^2-2x-1$ are $1+\sqrt2$ and $1-\sqrt2$, and the other root $1-\sqrt2$ is absolutely less than $1$.

This makes $1+\sqrt2$ a [Pisot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number), from which the the property you've noticed follows.

More concretely: The sequence
$$ a_n = (1+\sqrt2)^n + (1-\sqrt2)^n $$
satisfies the homogeneous linear recurrence relation
$$ a_n - 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} = 0 \qquad\text{that is, } a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} $$
because each of the two $n$th powers do so separately (note that the coefficients come from the polynomial above). We also find, by direct computation,
$$ a_0 = 2 \qquad a_1 = 2 $$
so all of the $a_n$s are integers. But $(1-\sqrt2)^n$ becomes smaller and smaller, so $(1+\sqrt2)^n$ ends up being closer and closer to the integer $a_n$.

Comment: Did you search for duplicates at all?

Answer (score 1):

You could observe the pattern if you would calculate the powers:
$$\begin{align}\alpha^1&=(1+\sqrt{2})^1=1+1\sqrt{2}\\
a^2&=(1+\sqrt{2})^2=3+2\sqrt{2}\\
a^3&=(1+\sqrt{2})^3=7+5\sqrt{2}\\
a^4&=(1+\sqrt{2})^4=17+12\sqrt{2}\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$
So, basically, the second terms are important. The coefficients $1,2,5,12,...$ form the recurrence relation [OEIS A000129](http://oeis.org/A000129):
$$a_1=1,a_2=2,a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},$$
Its solution is:
$$a_n=\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\left[(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n\right]$$
Hence:
$$a_n\sqrt{2}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n-2(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2}=\\
\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{2}-(1-\sqrt{2})^n$$
The first term is an integer, because its numerator is an even number and the second term approaches $0$ for large $n$, because $|1-\sqrt{2}|<1$, which were also stated in other answers and comments.

Hence, you can generalize for $\alpha=1+\sqrt{k}$:
$$a_n\sqrt{k}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{k})^n+(1-\sqrt{k})^n}{2}-(1-\sqrt{k})^n$$
So, it depends on how fast the second term $(1-\sqrt{k})^n$ approaches $0$.