# Show that the recursive sequence $x_1 = 1$, $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2+x_n}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

It is required to prove that the recursive sequence $x_1 = 1$, $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2+x_n}$ is convergent.

Note that this sequence is oscillating, it converges to $\sqrt{2}-1$ and every element of the sequence is positive. Also note that $x_{2k}$ is an increasing sequence and that $x_{2k+1}$ is a decreasing sequence.

These are the correct facts that have been analyzed. However, it has not been possible to provide a proof of the convergence or of the above facts.

It is not clear how to prove that $x_{2k}$ is an increasing sequence, that is, in the induction hypothesis, it is given a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{2k} < x_{2(k+1)}$, which implies that $x_{2(k+1)+1} = \frac{1}{2+x_{2(k+1)}} < \frac{1}{2+x_{2k}} = x_{2k+1}$.

By a similar argument, since $x_{2(k+1)+1} < x_{2k+1}$, it follows that
$$x_{2(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2+x_{2k+1}} < \frac{1}{2 + x_{2(k+1)+1}} = x_{2(k+2)}$$

Thus, $x_{2k}$ is an increasing sequence. By a similar argument, $x_{2k+1}$ is a decreasing sequence.

But only two subsequences and not any subsequence were taken in order to guarantee the convergence of the original sequence.

It this the correct and formal approach for showing that the sequence is convergent? Supposedly convergence can be proved without making use of Cauchy sequences and furthermore, proving convergence by the definition of epsilon is not immediate, so it has not been achieved.

Any valuable and kindly contribution is appreciated.

Comment: If you can prove that the subsequence of all of the odd indexed elements converge to $~L_1,~$ that all of the even indexed elements converge to $~L_2,~$ and that $~L_1 = L_2,~$ then **you are done.**  Given that, my first try, for each subsequence, would be to try to prove that that it is bounded and monotonic, and therefore convergent.  Then, assuming that the underlying function of the subsequence is continuous, you can then compute the limit of the subsequence.

Comment: @user2661923 So accurate. Thanks!!

Comment: Alternatively, show that $ \lim |x_i - x_{i+1} | = 0$, whence the increasing+decreasing sequence means we have convergence.

Comment: Please consult [OEIS sequence A001333](https://oeis.org) for continued fraction convergents to sqrt(2). Also related is [MSE question 3210472](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210472/).

Comment: @AnneBauval Great! Is the generalization of taking only two subsequences. Appreciate a lot.

Comment: @Somos Thanks for the resources! Very valuable.